# Analyzing a heap dump for out of memory error

Tags: java, hibernate, memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to analyze an issue using the heap dump of OOME, for this I use MAT.
I read about how to use MAT [here](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/21/10-tips-for-using-the-eclipse-memory-analyzer/).

It is a web application which is deployed on tomcat server and uses spring and hibernate. When I see the dominator tree for the dump, I can only see the hibernate objects, does this means that the memory leak is caused my hibernate holding the objects in the memory, or I am missing something here ?

Below is the screenshot of the dominator tree.
[image]

Comment: Really are you sure that it is really a leak? may be it just not enough memory. Looking at diagrams is not enough to understand cause of leak - you need to find objects that was not garbage collected but have to be, and understand who keeps a reference on them and why.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it looks like it is a leak, as when I inspect that object inside the hibernate map, it contains the data that I only use when I need to insert in the DB, which is done by a particular flow and is not very common.

Answer (score 2):

From the image that you have uploaded we cannot come to a conclusion that there is a memory leakage and the object that is shown is the cause of the memory leak.

Basically an object gets garbage collected by the JVM if it is not referenced by any other object. Memory leak is a situation where an object which would not be logically useful any more but stays in the memory because of an unwanted reference by another object in the memory.

If you are trying to test memory leakage in your application all you have to do is to identify the object which gets accumulated in the heap every time you access the application. To effectively identify the objects first take and initial heap. Then perform some action in your application. Then leave the application so that GC will happen and then take a heap dump. The tool provides an option to compare the heap dumps which will identify the object that has drastically increased from the base heap dump. Then you can drill into the object to identify who is holding the reference of this object.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the jvisualvm profiler with enabled "record allocation stack traces" option to find where these objects are created, then you can analyze where you store it...